# Zero-Knowledge proof with the paillier cryptosystem

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, paillier

For a paillier cryptosystem how can I perform a zero-knowledge proof?

Given a set of values:

- 0001
- 0010
- 0100
- 1000

This would be for use in a voting system where we want to ensure we where given a value from the set of acceptable ballots without knowing which if the values where selected.

I have found some information suggesting it is possible but I can't find a succinct set of steps or explanation for how this could be accomplished.

Comment: The keywords you should use in your research are "proof of set membership" and "range proof", but I am not sure if you can find a construction for Paillier - if you choose the cryptosystem first, you are bound to what is possible there - you can't just add some random property.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found an implementation here: https://paillier.daylightingsociety.org/Paillier_Zero_Knowledge_Proof.pdf

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged here, so -1. I suggest you edit to answer your question. Then we can upvote.